# Trying to calculate the the price of product in Swift3 Tableview controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to calculate the total of product price all the products. So, I am able to get the total but it is generating array of ouput. But I only need a final total.

This is my git repo:[(github.com/sulkytejas/shopping-cart)]

code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {    
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartCell", for: indexPath)
  let order = orders?[indexPath.row]
  let prices = [order?.product?.price]    
  print("in table view")
  for price in prices  {
    total += Double(price!)
  }     
  print (total)
  cell.textLabel?.text = order?.product?.name
  return cell
}
```

Output :

```
 in table view
1810636.0
in table view
1810676.0
in table view
1810766.0
in table view
1810806.0
in table view
1810821.0
in table view
1810911.0
in table view
1810951.0
```

Comment: Do you want the total of all orders in the table or all products in each order? (ie one grand total, or one total per row)?  I think you want the first, so `cellForRowAt` isn't the right place to do this, as it will be called for each row in the table and will potentially be called for each row more than once.

Comment: https://github.com/sulkytejas/image-cart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change readOrdersFromArchive function in orders.swift file. If you don't have order history, this function always returns nil value. That is why you can not append any order in the orders array in your addToCartPressed function.

```
class func readOrdersFromArchive() -> [Order]? 
{
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: archiveFilePath()) as? [Order] ?? [Order]()
}
```

I was able to see the total value after adding the code below.

```
var total = 0.0


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    orders = Orders.readOrdersFromArchive()

    if let orders = orders {

       for order in orders  {

          total += (order.product?.price!)!

          }
       }

       print(total)

 }
```

I just moved the for loop from cellForRowAtIndexPath to viewWillAppear. It is not a proper place to calculate total value because it gets called every time tableview configure its cell.

Comment: I am using seque to pass the data. I have declared total in the cart view controller class and tried to do addition in tableview for cell function.

Comment: The addition does work, but it is producing mutiple  outputs. I just want the final output. I tried loading the output from View didl load but it does not show up in the console. it gives the blank output

Comment: Does cartVC have order array as a local variable? Could you print out the passed object value after selecting product in ProductVC?  How about putting code in the viewWillAppear function?

Comment: The total is a local variable, prices are being called from ProductViewController.

Comment: So I tried printing it from viewWillApprear and the after debugging I saw that  values are being passed but it still doesnot print out in the console?

Comment: This is my git repo:[link(https://github.com/sulkytejas/shopping-cart)]...I am sorry, should have done this earlier. May be you can suggest me better now

Comment: I did the changes you suggested..So If you observe I have declared var total = 1.0    so when I try to output from viewDIDload it gives me 1.0 now instead of the total which I am calculating under the func tableview

Comment: https://github.com/sulkytejas/shopping-cart/blob/master/ImageStream/CartViewController.swift

Comment: There is varaible after didset function is closed, do you want to move this conversation to chat, my repo is low to do so

Comment: No, that was already working. If you go to cart section it should show the total of all the orders

Comment: Worked.. where exactly I went wrong? If you can explain

Answer (score 1):

```
let prices = [order?.product?.price]
```

What's going on here? This looks like an order has only one product? And you wrap the price of that one product in an array resulting in an array with a single price?

I have no idea what your interface is here, but it seems like you want something more like:

```
let prices = order.products.map() { $0.price }
```

This would get all the products an array, then make a new array with the price of each product.

Comment: I have 4 products at the moment and every product has a object attribute called product.price.

Comment: I have 4 products at the moment and every product has a object attribute called product.price. So in ProductViewController there is a addToCart Button. When you press that button the product object is send to cartViewController. Where I am tying to add all the product.price to give total price.

Answer (score 0):

Your array of output has come from your code being run for each cell you have in your table view, which from your output seems to be 7.

If you only want to output the final total then you need to call

`print (total)`

outside of the `tableView()` function. An ideal place would be in the`viewDidLoad()` function.

Comment: I tried loading from viewDidLoad and viewWillApprear but it does not work

Comment: where ever you have created your `orders` object you should put your for-in loop and `print()` statement

Comment: Did that..   
This is my git repo:[link(github.com/sulkytejas/shopping-cart)]... If you can have a look

Answer (score 0):

The total should be computed outside the tableview delegates, because as mentioned by @Paulw11, it will be called for every row every time you scroll or view the tableview. Best option would be to create a method for computing the total in the model itself, or in an extension to the model from where you are populating the table.

What is the datatype of `orders` here?

Comment: The data type of an order is Array

Comment: What is the output when you try to print the total inside viewWillAppear

Comment: Yes, so I am populating the table in CartViewController but the add to product action is performed in ProductVC

Comment: The output is 1.0
1.0
in table view
3001.0
in table view
6001.0
in table view
906001.0
in table view
1806001.0

Comment: I have shared my github repo if you can have a look

Comment: There is varirable after Didset func is closed

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {    
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartCell", for: indexPath)
  let order = orders?[indexPath.row]
  let prices = [order?.product?.price]    
  let localTotal:Double = 0.0    

  print("in table view")
  for price in prices  {
    localTotal += Double(price!)
  }     
  print (localTotal)
 total = localTotal
  print (total)
  cell.textLabel?.text = order?.product?.name
  return cell
}
```